# What will happen to the bullet when Deadpool is shot?

Tags: deadpool

Suppose Deadpool was shot and the bullet stays in his body. What will happen to the bullet? Would Deadpool remove them? Or would be be left behind?

Comment: Good question.  Deadpool does seem to get shot surprisingly often.

Comment: In X2 Wolverine was shot in the head and he was dead/unconscious for a while then the bullet just popped out and he woke up. I imagine the same would happen to Deadpool? In the Deadpool movie you could see that a lot of them were clean through and not stuck in him.

Comment: @Probst wat about the shot in the ass :p

Comment: @Probst: Wolverine's skeleton is laced with Adamantium, including his forehead. The bullet did not enter his skull (it was smashed and can be seen sticking out of the skin). The skin pushes it out while closing up the hole during regeneration. He was not dead, just unconscious, and only for a couple of minutes (probably from the shock). Deadpool, on the other hand, doesn't have that protection. No indestructible bone to stop the bullet. It would get lodged deep in his body and likely stay there (the same for Wolverine, if he had been shot in the gut instead of the head)...

Comment: @Probst: ... I would not expect a healing factor, whether Wolverine's or Deadpool's, to be able to push a bullet in deep tissue all the way out of the body the same way it entered, too much tissue in the way, the outer holes in the skin are likely to close up before the inner tissue can push the bullet far enough to exit. I don't think a healing factor is coordinated enough to make the skin wait for the inner organs to finish first. Makes more sense to close the outside sooner rather than later to avoid infections and such.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I saw such thing in the movie. But we know he has a strong healing factor. When he cut off his hand to let himself free from Colossus' handcuff, we sam him grow a baby hand. That implies he has regeneration powers.

In comics, it is not only the bullets that impales him.

[image]

In these moments, I hardly think he waits until the object inside removes itself/pops outside from his body.

[image]

If the object is small enough like a bullet or he has more than one object impaled, he lets it pop out or maybe he doesn't realise that he has a bullet in him. He removes what he can remove and lets the others find a way out.

His regeneration ability is very strong and providing in these cases.

Sorry about the blood and guts. *Literally*.